# I need to count the today created account in Cake 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I need to count the users, but my condition is only if their account have been created today. I have a users table with a created field (datetime) for each rows. How can i do it in Cakephp, i didn't find the answer in the documentation.

```
$usersNewCount = Number::format($this->Users->find()->where(['created' => 'CURDATE()'])->count());
```

I tried with CURDATE, and of course it's not working, i guess Cakephp has a specific function for te datetime field ?

Comment: the problem is that `created` is a datetime field, I guess. So try `['DATE(created)' => 'CURDATE()']` in your conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing there won't work for various reasons.

1. You cannot pass SQL snippets in the value part of the conditions array, it will be escaped and you'll end up with a string comparison like `created = 'CURDATE()'`, you'd either have to pass the whole condition as a string, or use [**raw expressions**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#raw-expressions).
2. Even when properly passing `CURDATE()`, the comparison won't work as the `created` column has a time part.

While it is possible to circumvent the former problem by transforming the column, you should try to avoid that whenever possible! Comparing to calculated columns like `DATE(created) = CURDATE()` will make using indices impossible, and thus massively degrade performance!

So unless you have an extra column that holds just the date part, your best bet is a `BETWEEN` comparison which is the equivalent to `a >= x AND a <= y`, and in order to stay cross DBMS compatible, this is best to be done by passing dates from PHP, ie not using DBMS specific date and time functions like `CURDATE()`.

```php
$this->Users
    ->find()
    ->where(function (\Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression $exp, \Cake\ORM\Query $query) {
        $from = (new \DateTime())->setTime(0, 0, 0);
        $to = (new \DateTime())->setTime(23, 59, 59);
        return $exp->between('Users.created', $from, $to, 'datetime');
    })
    ->count()
```

This will create a query similar to

```sql
SELECT
    (COUNT(*)) AS `count`
FROM
    users Users
WHERE
    Users.created BETWEEN '2015-05-26 00:00:00' AND '2015-05-26 23:59:59'
```

See also

- **[API > \Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression::between()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Database.Expression.QueryExpression.html#_between)**

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

```
$usersNewCount = Number::format($this->Users->find()->where([
    'DATE(created) = CURDATE()'
])->count());
```

Note that passing it in form `where(['DATE(created)' => 'CURDATE()'])` will not work, since `CURDATE()` will be interpreted as a string.

Comment: You should always try to avoid comparing to calculated columns, as this will make using indices impossible.

Comment: This answer works for me though maybe it has a draw back like indices can't be used.

Answer (score 0):

When doing 'created' => 'CURDATE()' you are checking for a complete match, getting '2015-05-26', without a time. You need to check for a time interval:

```
$usersNewCount = Number::format(
    $this->Users->find()->where([
        'created >=' => date('Y-m-d').' 00:00:00',
        'created <=' => date('Y-m-d').' 23:59:59'
    ])->count());
```

Comment: This won't work, the value part is going to be escaped, and if it wouldn't, you'd end up with invalid SQL like `CURDATE() 00:00:00`.