# cakephp 3.5 gives empty result but the query generated by query builder gives data if executed at mysql

Tags: php, mysql, query-builder, cakephp-3.4

The following code gives empty result but if the query which is generated by the query builder is executed in mysql console than it returns value.

Code:

```
$query = $this->Vehicles->find()
            ->where([
        'Vehicles.first_enlisting_date IS NOT' => null,
        'Vehicles.second_enlisting_date IS NOT' => null,
        'Vehicles.third_enlisting_date IS' => null,
        'DATE(Vehicles.second_enlisting_date) <=' => 'CURDATE()-INTERVAL 7 DAY'
    ]);
```

It gives the following empty array if print_r

```
Cake\ORM\ResultSet Object
(
    [items] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

The query generated by query builder is as follows:

```
Cake\ORM\Query Object
(
    [(help)] => This is a Query object, to get the results execute or iterate it.
    [sql] => SELECT Vehicles.id AS `Vehicles__id`, Vehicles.title AS `Vehicles__title`, Vehicles.user_id AS `Vehicles__user_id`, Vehicles.dealer_id AS `Vehicles__dealer_id`, Vehicles.model_id AS `Vehicles__model_id`, Vehicles.brand_id AS `Vehicles__brand_id`, Vehicles.body_id AS `Vehicles__body_id`, Vehicles.year AS `Vehicles__year`, Vehicles.price AS `Vehicles__price`, Vehicles.nada_price AS `Vehicles__nada_price`, Vehicles.description AS `Vehicles__description`, Vehicles.latitude AS `Vehicles__latitude`, Vehicles.longitude AS `Vehicles__longitude`, Vehicles.zipcode AS `Vehicles__zipcode`, Vehicles.mileage AS `Vehicles__mileage`, Vehicles.vin_number AS `Vehicles__vin_number`, Vehicles.status AS `Vehicles__status`, Vehicles.vehicle_condition AS `Vehicles__vehicle_condition`, Vehicles.vin_image AS `Vehicles__vin_image`, Vehicles.image AS `Vehicles__image`, Vehicles.first_enlisting_date AS `Vehicles__first_enlisting_date`, Vehicles.second_enlisting_date AS `Vehicles__second_enlisting_date`, Vehicles.third_enlisting_date AS `Vehicles__third_enlisting_date`, Vehicles.listing_expired AS `Vehicles__listing_expired`, Vehicles.deleted_from_listing AS `Vehicles__deleted_from_listing`, Vehicles.created AS `Vehicles__created`, Vehicles.modified AS `Vehicles__modified` FROM vehicles Vehicles WHERE ((Vehicles.first_enlisting_date) IS NOT NULL AND (Vehicles.second_enlisting_date) IS NULL AND (Vehicles.third_enlisting_date) IS NULL AND Vehicles.first_enlisting_date < :c0 AND Vehicles.deleted_from_listing = :c1 AND Vehicles.listing_expired = :c2 AND Vehicles.status = :c3)
    [params] => Array
        (
            [:c0] => Array
                (
                    [value] => DATE(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
                    [type] => date
                    [placeholder] => c0
                )

            [:c1] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 0
                    [type] => boolean
                    [placeholder] => c1
                )

            [:c2] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 0
                    [type] => boolean
                    [placeholder] => c2
                )

            [:c3] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 1
                    [type] => integer
                    [placeholder] => c3
                )

        )

    [defaultTypes] => Array
        (
            [Vehicles__id] => integer
            [Vehicles.id] => integer
            [id] => integer
            [Vehicles__title] => string
            [Vehicles.title] => string
            [title] => string
            [Vehicles__user_id] => integer
            [Vehicles.user_id] => integer
            [user_id] => integer
            [Vehicles__dealer_id] => integer
            [Vehicles.dealer_id] => integer
            [dealer_id] => integer
            [Vehicles__model_id] => string
            [Vehicles.model_id] => string
            [model_id] => string
            [Vehicles__brand_id] => string
            [Vehicles.brand_id] => string
            [brand_id] => string
            [Vehicles__body_id] => string
            [Vehicles.body_id] => string
            [body_id] => string
            [Vehicles__year] => string
            [Vehicles.year] => string
            [year] => string
            [Vehicles__price] => float
            [Vehicles.price] => float
            [price] => float
            [Vehicles__nada_price] => float
            [Vehicles.nada_price] => float
            [nada_price] => float
            [Vehicles__description] => text
            [Vehicles.description] => text
            [description] => text
            [Vehicles__latitude] => string
            [Vehicles.latitude] => string
            [latitude] => string
            [Vehicles__longitude] => string
            [Vehicles.longitude] => string
            [longitude] => string
            [Vehicles__zipcode] => integer
            [Vehicles.zipcode] => integer
            [zipcode] => integer
            [Vehicles__mileage] => string
            [Vehicles.mileage] => string
            [mileage] => string
            [Vehicles__vin_number] => string
            [Vehicles.vin_number] => string
            [vin_number] => string
            [Vehicles__status] => integer
            [Vehicles.status] => integer
            [status] => integer
            [Vehicles__vehicle_condition] => tinyinteger
            [Vehicles.vehicle_condition] => tinyinteger
            [vehicle_condition] => tinyinteger
            [Vehicles__vin_image] => string
            [Vehicles.vin_image] => string
            [vin_image] => string
            [Vehicles__image] => string
            [Vehicles.image] => string
            [image] => string
            [Vehicles__first_enlisting_date] => date
            [Vehicles.first_enlisting_date] => date
            [first_enlisting_date] => date
            [Vehicles__second_enlisting_date] => date
            [Vehicles.second_enlisting_date] => date
            [second_enlisting_date] => date
            [Vehicles__third_enlisting_date] => date
            [Vehicles.third_enlisting_date] => date
            [third_enlisting_date] => date
            [Vehicles__listing_expired] => boolean
            [Vehicles.listing_expired] => boolean
            [listing_expired] => boolean
            [Vehicles__deleted_from_listing] => boolean
            [Vehicles.deleted_from_listing] => boolean
            [deleted_from_listing] => boolean
            [Vehicles__created] => datetime
            [Vehicles.created] => datetime
            [created] => datetime
            [Vehicles__modified] => datetime
            [Vehicles.modified] => datetime
            [modified] => datetime
        )

    [decorators] => 0
    [executed] => 
    [hydrate] => 1
    [buffered] => 1
    [formatters] => 0
    [mapReducers] => 0
    [contain] => Array
        (
        )

    [matching] => Array
        (
        )

    [extraOptions] => Array
        (
        )

    [repository] => App\Model\Table\VehiclesTable Object
        (
            [registryAlias] => Vehicles
            [table] => vehicles
            [alias] => Vehicles
            [entityClass] => \Cake\ORM\Entity
            [associations] => Array
                (
                    [0] => dealers
                    [1] => users
                    [2] => model
                    [3] => brands
                    [4] => vdetails
                    [5] => series
                    [6] => offers
                )

            [behaviors] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Timestamp
                )

            [defaultConnection] => default
            [connectionName] => default
        )

)
```

Now if I run the query in mysql console then I get value. Here is the mysql code which I executed

```
SELECT Vehicles.id AS `Vehicles__id`, Vehicles.title AS `Vehicles__title`, Vehicles.user_id AS `Vehicles__user_id`, Vehicles.dealer_id AS `Vehicles__dealer_id`, Vehicles.model_id AS `Vehicles__model_id`, Vehicles.brand_id AS `Vehicles__brand_id`, Vehicles.body_id AS `Vehicles__body_id`, Vehicles.year AS `Vehicles__year`, Vehicles.price AS `Vehicles__price`, Vehicles.nada_price AS `Vehicles__nada_price`, Vehicles.description AS `Vehicles__description`, Vehicles.latitude AS `Vehicles__latitude`, Vehicles.longitude AS `Vehicles__longitude`, Vehicles.zipcode AS `Vehicles__zipcode`, Vehicles.mileage AS `Vehicles__mileage`, Vehicles.vin_number AS `Vehicles__vin_number`, Vehicles.status AS `Vehicles__status`, Vehicles.vehicle_condition AS `Vehicles__vehicle_condition`, Vehicles.vin_image AS `Vehicles__vin_image`, Vehicles.image AS `Vehicles__image`, Vehicles.first_enlisting_date AS `Vehicles__first_enlisting_date`, Vehicles.second_enlisting_date AS `Vehicles__second_enlisting_date`, Vehicles.third_enlisting_date AS `Vehicles__third_enlisting_date`, Vehicles.listing_expired AS `Vehicles__listing_expired`, Vehicles.deleted_from_listing AS `Vehicles__deleted_from_listing`, Vehicles.created AS `Vehicles__created`, Vehicles.modified AS `Vehicles__modified` FROM vehicles Vehicles WHERE ((Vehicles.first_enlisting_date) IS NOT NULL AND (Vehicles.second_enlisting_date) IS NULL AND (Vehicles.third_enlisting_date) IS NULL AND Vehicles.first_enlisting_date < DATE(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND Vehicles.deleted_from_listing = 0 AND Vehicles.listing_expired = 0 AND Vehicles.status = 1)
```

Then I get the result:

[image]

Is it causing for the date functions?
One important thing should be mention that the code is working at Ubuntu machine but not at windows machine!

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please add the complete code from calling `$this->Vehicles->find()` to your `print_r()`. Be sure to understand when cakephp executes the query (https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#queries-are-lazily-evaluated).

Comment: One important thing should be mention that the code is working at Ubuntu machine but not at windows machine!

Comment: This has been answered many times. [Here's one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30446859/i-need-to-count-the-today-created-account-in-cake-3).

Comment: I've found my answer from your given link. Actually though the accepted answer was good for details and to understand a concept but the second answer works for me. It is mentioned in the second answer that: `Note that passing it in form where(['DATE(created)' => 'CURDATE()']) will not work, since CURDATE() will be interpreted as a string.`

Comment: So my modified code looks like as follows: `$firstExpiredConditions = [
            'Vehicles.first_enlisting_date IS NOT' => null,
            'Vehicles.second_enlisting_date IS' => null,
            'Vehicles.third_enlisting_date IS' => null,
            'DATE(Vehicles.first_enlisting_date) <= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)'
        ];`